# What is the status of @ and $ characters in C++?

Tags: c++

C++ syntax uses almost all printable ASCII characters and some of them in several contexts. Only two unused are @ and $ characters. Why they are not used? Are they reserved for some "meta" purpose?

Comment: Note that this makes `@` useful in documentation where it often stands for “any operator”.

Comment: *Why they are not used?*  They were not available in all the popular character sets at the inception of C (and its predecessor, B) back in the late 1960s and early 1970s.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is [implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-defined-behavior.html) defined (so you should avoid using them if you care about portability).

Some compilers (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/))  accept `$` in identifiers.

BTW, the [backquote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) ` is also unused in C++.

Notice that early definition of C or C++ languages did not require (and where not used) on systems using ASCII. This explains why some ASCII characters remain unused. (Some systems used [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) and had a C compiler).

Read also about the (ugly) [trigraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) (they might go away in [C++17](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17))

Be aware of [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (perhaps some compilers accept it as an extension...)

As [Jules commented](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/66037/jules), read also about [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Comment: Good answer. The only relevant point I can think of that you haven't covered is that these characters are often used in name mangling schemes (presumably because they shouldn't show up in legal identifiers therefore there's no need to use an escaping scheme to prevent collisions).